# shiny app error cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to run this shiny app which takes in some data,and then  processes it to give out some proportion tables in a variable called 'out'. These tables are then plotted using a function which is mapped using the purrr package.  The app is giving me the following error though in a section where I am trying to define a function:-

> ```
> cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
> ```

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = h4("proportion graphs", align="center")), sidebarLayout( sidebarPanel( ),
                                                                              
                                                                              mainPanel(
                                                                                # create a uiOutput
                                                                                uiOutput("plots")
                                                                              )
  )
  
))


server<- shinyServer(
  
  function(input, output) {
    #1 Dataset l
    l<- reactive({
      f<- list(`0` = structure(list(X70 = "D", X71 = "C", X72 = "C", X73 = "A", X74 = "B", X75 = "C", X76 = "D", X77 = NA_character_, X78 = "B", X79 = "D", X80 = "C", Q = 1), row.names = 32L, class = "data.frame"), `1` = structure(list(X70 = c("D", "B", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("B", "B", "C", "C", "C", NA, "D", "B", "C", "A", "C"), X72 = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "B", NA), X73 = c("B", "C", "C", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "C", NA), X74 = c("B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "D", NA, "D", "D", "D", NA), X75 = c("C", "C", "B", "C", "D", "D", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C"), X76 = c("D", "A", "D", "B", "D", "C", "D", "A", "A", "D", "B"), X77 = c("D", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D"), X78 = c("B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", NA), X79 = c("C", "C", NA, NA, "D", "A", "A", "A", "D", "A", "D"), X80 = c("B", "A", NA, NA, "B", "C", "B", NA, "B", "C", "A"), Q = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1)), row.names = c(8L, 10L, 12L, 17L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 45L), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(X70 = c("D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "D", "B"), X72 = c("D", "C", "D", "A", "A", "C", "D", "C", NA, "D", "C", "B"), X73 = c("B", "D", "D", "C", "B", "D", "D", "D", NA, NA, "C", "A"), X74 = c("D", "C", "B", "D", "C", "B", "C", "C", "B", NA, "C", "D"), X75 = c("B", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C"), X76 = c("A", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X77 = c("B", "B", "D", "B", NA, "B", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), X78 = c("C", "D", "C", "B", NA, "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "C", NA), X79 = c("A", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", "A", NA, "A", "D", "B", NA), X80 = c(NA, "C", "C", "A", NA, "C", "C", NA, "B", "C", "C", NA), Q = c(2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 22L, 26L, 37L, 39L, 43L), class = "data.frame"), `3` = structure(list(X70 = c("A", "A", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("B", "C", "D", "D", "C", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "D"), X72 = c("B", "C", NA, "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "D", "B"), X73 = c(NA, "C", "C", "A", "D", "C", "A", "A", "D", "B", "D", "B"), X74 = c(NA, "C", "D", "B", "A", "D", NA, "D", "B", "A", "D", "A"), X75 = c(NA, "C", "B", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C", "D"), X76 = c(NA, "D", "A", "B", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X77 = c(NA, "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B", NA, "C", "D", "D"), X78 = c(NA, "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "D", "C", "C", "C"), X79 = c(NA, "D", "D", NA, "B", "D", "A", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A"), X80 = c(NA, "C", "C", NA, "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C"), Q = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2)), row.names = c(2L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 29L, 30L, 34L, 36L, 41L, 44L), class = "data.frame"), `4` = structure(list(X70 = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), X71 = c("A", NA, "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C"), X72 = c("B", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", NA, "A"), X73 = c(NA, "D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "C", "A", "A", "C"), X74 = c("C", "A", "C", "D", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "D", "D", "D"), X75 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C"), X76 = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A"), X77 = c(NA, "B", "D", "B", NA, "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", NA, "C"), X78 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C"), X79 = c("D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C"), X80 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", NA, "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A"), Q = c(2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 23L, 24L, 31L, 40L, 42L, 46L, 47L, 48L), class = "data.frame")) })
    
    
    #2 Vector u
    u <- reactive({
      u <- c("D", "B", "C", "A")
    })
    
    #3 reactive expression to process data
    out <- reactive({
      l <- l()
      u <- u()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      
      lapply(l, function(dat) 
        asplit(as.data.frame(t(sapply(dat, function(x) 
          proportions(table(factor(unlist(x), levels = u)))))), 1) ) %>%
        transpose %>%
        map(bind_rows, .id = 'grp')
    })
    
    #4 render plots 
    output$plots <- renderUI({
      
      plots <- function(x){
        d = x %>% 
          as.data.frame() %>%
          tidyr::pivot_longer(!grp) %>%
          dplyr::group_by(name) %>% 
          dplyr::mutate(n = 1:n())
        
        ggplot(data = d) + 
          geom_path(aes(x = grp, y = value, group = factor(name), color = factor(name)), size = 0.7) +
          geom_point(aes(x = grp, y = value, color = factor(name)), size = 2) +
          geom_text(data = d %>% filter(n == max(n)), aes(x = grp, y = value, label = name, color = factor(name)), nudge_x = 0.2) + 
          labs(x = "Group", y = "P", title = "") + 
          theme_bw() +
          theme(legend.position = "none")
      }
      plot_objects <- purrr::map(out(), plots)
      
      
    })
    
  } )

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `renderUI` function needs `renderPlot` to be called on the `ggplot` graphs. Here is `output$plots` with the addition.

```
output$plots <-
    renderUI({
        plots <- function(x) {
            d = x %>%
                as.data.frame() %>%
                tidyr::pivot_longer(!grp) %>%
                dplyr::group_by(name) %>%
                dplyr::mutate(n = 1:n())
            
            gg <- ggplot(data = d) + # put ggplot into a variable
                geom_path(aes(
                    x = grp,
                    y = value,
                    group = factor(name),
                    color = factor(name)
                ),
                size = 0.7) +
                geom_point(aes(
                    x = grp,
                    y = value,
                    color = factor(name)
                ), size = 2) +
                geom_text(
                    data = d %>% filter(n == max(n)),
                    aes(
                        x = grp,
                        y = value,
                        label = name,
                        color = factor(name)
                    ),
                    nudge_x = 0.2
                ) +
                labs(x = "Group",
                         y = "P",
                         title = "") +
                theme_bw() +
                theme(legend.position = "none")
            renderPlot(gg)  # call renderPlot on the ggplot variable
        }
```

Comment: Works perfectly!!

Comment: I had almost lost hope thank you so much! This was the last part of my project and i am so glad i can finally get it over with

Comment: Any idea on how i would display a single graph? I tried plot_objects$X74 but i get the error 'object of type 'closure' is not subsettable'

Comment: Strictly speaking this is a second question so you should raise another post. However, below this line `plot_objects <- purrr::map(out(), plots)` do this `plot_objects[1]  # plot 1 only` . If this doesn't work then raise a new question but please  make your reproducible example much smaller because it makes it easier for solvers to work on.

Comment: I will keep that in mind from next time. Also it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: Can I suggest you up vote the comment to indicate that it is helpful?

Comment: I am so sorry i started using stackexchange a month ago. I will get more familiar with the rules. Very sorry for that